# Simple webpack project output blank page

Tags: node.js, webpack, vue.js

Full code: https://github.com/kenpeter/test_element_ui
I try to follow this simple [guide](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/quickstart), but it is not outputting anything.

git clone https://github.com/kenpeter/test_element_ui

yarn install

yarn dev

Visit localhost:808x?, blank page

Comment: Any errors on the console?

Comment: no, unfortunately.